# iOS Silent Push Notification does not wake up application on some devices

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, silent-notification

We are sending silent pushes to wake up our application. (We do use priority 5 and push type 'background')

This is working on most iOS devices.

But out of the blue 2 iOS devices (one on iOS 14, one is downgraded again to 14) do not wake up anymore.

- We tried reinstalling the application but no luck.
- Badges are set correctly.
- When attaching the device to the console we see this log:

```
dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[141] <Notice>: Push not allowed for <private>
```

- When comparing to a device where this does work we are not seeing the above log but we do see:

```
dasd(DuetActivitySchedulerDaemon)[125] <Notice>: com.apple.pushLaunch.appId:A53B1D:[    {name: DeviceActivityPolicy, policyWeight: 5.000, response: {Decision: Can Proceed, Score: 0.05}}
] sumScores:92.260000, denominator:97.010000, FinalDecision: Can Proceed FinalScore: 0.951036}
```

Does anybody know what we are missing or how we can debug further?

Comment: Are they plugged into power? The [docs](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/usernotifications/setting_up_a_remote_notification_server/sending_notification_requests_to_apns) say “Specify 5 to send the notification based on power considerations on the user’s device. Use this priority for notifications that have a payload that includes the content-available key.”  Also, you haven’t force-quit the apps, have you?

Comment: Yes, I tested with the device plugged into power, wifi, and not killed.

Comment: Hey @Lies.
Have you found the reason of this behaviour? I have similar situation,